Antimicrobial for HVAC Condensate Line
I am interested in utilizing copper to minimize condensate growth, which inevitably leads to plugged up PVC line.  I would like to do this at scale (20+ units). Removal of said growth is regular maintenance task I have to perform:  I would like to do less of this by preventing the growth.
I was thinking that a T in the line, that would allow a piece of copper to be pinned in place by gravity.  The vertical part of the T would hold the copper pieces.
Any reason why this would not work and has anyone had success with a similar solution?

I’m voting to close this question because it is more a pathogen/ chemical question rather than about Home improvement.

The easiest solution is to add 1/4 cup of bleach to the AC drain line 2 times a year.

It's about maintaining an HVAC system.  That's certainly on-topic.

It is not about maintenance. There was no question of how to maintain.  This question is about opinion over the ability of copper to remove organic compounds from condensation originated water.  Further there is the belief that this is for a multi unit building.
